# Crop imagen con php y jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, php7, php5

en esta oportunidad los molesto ya que estoy con un problema en un script, la idea es hacer un crop de una imagen, mostrarla y luego subirla al servidor, el problema es que a veces se sube al servidor y a veces no, aparece el archivo sin peso, es decir 0kb, este es el script y la libreria

Javascript

Libereria croppie --> https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/blob/master/croppie.js || https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$image_crop = $('#upload-image').croppie({
    enableExif: false,
    viewport: {
        width: 800,
        height: 560,
        type: 'square'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 800,
        height: 560
    }
});
$('#images').on('change', function () { 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
            url: e.target.result
        }).then(function(){
            console.log('jQuery bind complete');
        });         
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
$('.cropped_image').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    $image_crop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image":response, "path":'11', "usuario":'22'},
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".imgyacargada").html("<p style='color:#146666; font-weight:bold;'>Procesando imagen, espere por favor...</p>");
                    $(".cropped_image").fadeOut("fast");
                },
            success: function (data) {
                html = '<img src="' + response + '" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:200px" />';
                $("#upload-image-i").html(html);
                $(".cropped_image").stop().fadeIn("fast");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

});

y el codigo php que recibe es el siguiente:

```
$croped_image = $_POST['image'];


    list($type, $croped_image) = explode(';', $croped_image);
    list(, $croped_image)      = explode(',', $croped_image);
    $croped_image = base64_decode($croped_image);


    $ruta="archivos";
    if( !file_exists( $ruta ) ){
        mkdir($ruta);
    }
    $ruta .= '/';


    $nombrealeatorio = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 5)), 0, 7) . '.jpg';


$fp = fopen("$ruta$nombrealeatorio", 'w');
fwrite($fp, "$croped_image");
fclose($fp);
```

El codigo funciona solo con imagenes de bajo peso ¿Que puede ser? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Definitivamente se lo que puede ser,  pero creo que de aqui a unas horas ya tendras una solucion por parte de otros miembros... si no es asi en unas horas dare mi respuesta,  aca esta algo tarde...

Comment: Luego de muchas pruebas creo que me doy por vencido, es muy raro lo que sucede, he probado de bajo peso y mucho tamaño y funciona perfecto, he probado de mucho peso y un tamaño razonable y falla, no puedo encontrar un patrón para poder determinar porque falla ¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Comment: De hecho eso que dijiste es justo lo que pense que pasaba,  pero pues... al ver que no subes archivos directamente si no que aparentemente son imagenes en base64, la cosa va por otro lado... voy a analizar tu codigo mejor y ver que puedo encontrar,  aunque nunca he usado croppie...

Comment: Muchas gracias Riven!, yo tambien sigo investigando!